# How to show/hide a character in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, game-physics

I am thinking about a 2d endless runner game with a few choice of character. In my game I will place all characters but they will be deactivated by default.

I want to give a menu to choose which character player like to play with. When player will select a character that specific character will be activated to play.

I don't have any script yet. As I don't how to handle these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a script but it should just be a one line call in C# for `gameObject.SetActive(false)`

Documentation and example here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Answer (score -1):

As I worked with Unity I have acknowledged that the change of states of a certain object when the game is running is accessed by the script attached to it.